# Configure new SQL view doesn't appear for different DB's in the same PostGIS Database

Tags: postgis, geoserver, sql

I have PostGIS Database with different DB's. Each one of them has different workspace:store in Geoserver. When I'm opening Create new layer page and picking different workspace:store for some of them option "Configure new SQL view " appears and for some of them not. I could not find any correlations DB/workspace/store definition and this behavior... Any thoughts?